# Scroll NSTableView on load

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have a `NSViewController` containing a view-based table view. When I initialise the view controller and put its view on screent the table view is scrolled to the bottom. I would prefer instead to have the table view scrolled to the top.

I know the method `-scrollRowToVisible:` but I can't figure where to call it in order for the table view to first appear scrolled to the top. I tried inserting it at the end of the `-loadView` method of the `NSViewController` but obviously it doesn't work as the table view hasn't even loaded its rows yet at that point.

What would it be the best place to place the call to the `-scrollRowToVisible:` method? Or alternatively, is there a property to make the table view show it's first row instead of the last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the way to go..

-- you should call scroll once all the item / rows of a table got loaded/displayed in the tableview

-- Somewhere you would do reloadData, Possibly in the awake from nib, This is not a kind of blocking function, it will call some of the UI Delegate function, like

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn byItem:(id)item
```

Perhaps you should check here for the last item and there might be some Delegate function in the [NSTableViewUIDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), which tells you when an Item got loaded/displayed in the Table, there you can check for the last item , it means all the table item got loaded then its safe to call scrollToVisible

Comment: Thanks that worked. I ended up putting the call in `-tableView:rowViewForRow:`. I thought that putting it in any of the delegate method would cause a crash since the cells are not laid out completely yet but it doesn't. Thanks again.

Comment: There's no such thing as “NSTableViewUIDelegate”, and you linked to `UITableViewDelegate`, which is for the wrong platform.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but for the record, since I ran into this myself today:

The `NSScrollView` of your table view starts out scrolled to the bottom, most likely because the scroll view restores its last scroll position after closing the window last time.

This is part of the [User Interface Preservation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW26) / State Restoration feature.

To avoid that the scroll view restores the scroll position  (in fact, anything at all), you can subclass `NSScrollView` and subclass these:

```
class NonPreservingScrollView: NSScrollView {

    override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
        // Nothing
    }
    override func restoreState(with coder: NSCoder) {
        // Nothing
    }
}
```

Maybe a bit cleaner than trying to track when reloading data has finished and the scroll view won't move when the window loads...